# Securely Handling Session Keys in Excel for API Authentication

Tags: api, authentication, excel, vba

I'm working on an Excel tool that needs to synchronize with a CRM via its API. The CRM's API authentication process involves logging in with a username and password, after which a session key is provided for subsequent API calls.

My primary concern is about securely handling this session key:

Authentication:

How can I securely store and manage the session key within Excel after it's retrieved?
Are there established best practices or methods for handling session keys in Excel to ensure they aren't exposed or misused?
Development:

I'm considering using VBA within Excel for this task. Are there any inherent security risks or limitations with VBA in this context?
Alternatively, would an external Excel add-in provide better security features for this purpose?
Data Integrity:

Given that users have flexibility within Excel, what measures can I implement to ensure data integrity when syncing with the CRM?
I'm looking for technical solutions or established best practices to address these concerns. Any references or documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your threat model?

Comment: Mainly afraid of someone getting their hands on the Excel file and be able to connect to the CRM or get the credentials/API key

Comment: By "someone", you mean a user of the Excel tool? Someone who has already access to the Excel file and is allowed to sync with the CRM? Do you fear there is anything an authorized user of the tool could do which is not allowed for them, in case they take the session key and use it in context with a different program?

Comment: I thought enabling VBA was inherently a security risk which is why VBA macros are [disabled by default](https://www.theverge.com/2022/2/7/22922032/microsoft-block-office-vba-macros-default-change).  Would this require enabling VBA, or is there some other way to provide your functionality?

Comment: @JimmyJames: you are conflating two things. Enabling VBA is not more or less a security risk than allowing the user to run arbitrary executable files.  The security issue for Excel documents is that a malicious hacker may use such a document as a trojan for executable code when sending people email attachments. But the threat model of the OP is eactly the opposite here: not the author of the Excel file is the threat, but the user.

Comment: @DocBrown I don't think you follow my point here.  This will be distributed to users and it's not clear how. I'm asking how they will enable the functionality without potentially opening themselves to malicious code from other sources.

Comment: VBA within Excel is fully accessible (down to step-by-step debugging) for a motivated user as Microsoft effectively includes a full VBA IDE as part of Excel.  Nothing in flight in VBA is secret.

Comment: @Craig: sure, but programs written in other programming languages are also not immune against reverse engineering. And for VBA programs, one can also choose to  protect the source code by a password. So I fail to see why a VBA program should be introduce a higher security risk for the problem of handling the session key than something else which runs in the same environment and the same execution rights.